# format numbers of RUT with simple javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form where chilean customers need to write their security number ( RUT )

the format can be with 1.234.567-8 for old people or 12.345.678-9 for younger people

What I need is that when they type down their number the input text change as soon as they type down and start formatting the number with the two dots and - like in the example above

I created this code

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="cliente" id="cliente" 
       onkeydown = "this.value = this.value.replace( /^(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')" >
```

It works almost good but only with 9 digits RUTs but not with 8 digits RUTs, any idea how to accomplish this ?

Comment: Try changing the first `{1}` to `{1,2}` to match on a minimum of one character up to a maximum of two characters.

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic removes any - or . you previously put in it, or the user put in it, and then performs the reformatting.  It also fires on `keyup` rather than keydown as the new value would not have been added yet on the keydown.

```js
function formatCliente (cliente) {
  cliente.value = cliente.value
    .replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
    .replace( /^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="cliente"
       id="cliente" onkeyup="formatCliente(this)">
```

Comment: If i want to prevent them to type down letters from A to Z or other symbols ?

Comment: Modified it to remove anything that is not 0-9. @NICALANICA

Answer (score 0):

i've made an correction to accept a RUT that's end with letter (like 8.345.434-k or 20.432.345-k)

```
function formatCliente (cliente) {
  cliente.value = cliente.value
    .replace(/[^0-9\dkK]/g, '')
    .replace( /^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).